# Check the value of character variable

Tags: c

I'm writing some code for Arduino and I'm not sure if I'm checking the value of this character variable correctly. Can you please tell me if this is correct:

```
const char* front = "front";
const char* back = "back";

eyeballs(front);
eyeballs(back);

void eyeballs(const char* frontOrBack){ 

if (frontOrBack == "front") {
    digitalWrite(frontEyes, LOW);}//end if   
  else if (frontOrBack == "back") {
    digitalWrite(backEyes, LOW);}//end else*/
}
```

Comment: Isn't this more suited to stackoverflow, since there's nothing Arduino-specific about C string comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using C strings (array of characters) instead of the C++ String class, you cannot use the == operator.

Instead, you can use the C style [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function, which is also part of the C++ library:

```
    #include <string.h>
       .
       .
       .

    if (!strcmp(frontOrBack,"front")) {
        digitalWrite(frontEyes, LOW);}//end if   
    else if (!strcmp(frontOrBack,"back")) {
        digitalWrite(backEyes, LOW);}//end else*/
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to #include <string.h>

Comment: Thank you. Is that the only issue with my code? For some reason the ARduino IDE isn't catching the error.

Comment: @Armandas thx, updated.

Comment: @MichaelRader Syntactically, there is nothing wrong with your code, so the compiler doesn't display an error.  What you are doing is testing whether the address of the character array frontOrBack passed into the function eyeballs  is the same as the address of the constant character arrays "front" or "back", which will always be false.

Comment: Can you tell me why you have the `!` before `strcmp`?

Comment: @MichaelRader If you click on the link that I gave for the strcmp function, you will see (under Return Value) that it can return one of three values: >0 (e.g. 1) if the the first character of string1 is greater than the first character of string2; <0 (e.g. -1) if the the first character of string1 is less than the first character of string2; and 0 if the two strings are equal (which is what you are testing for).  Putting a ! in front of a variable or function in C or C++ is the same as testing for 0.  So I could have written this as "if (strcmp(frontOrBack,"front")==0)"

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be an enum.

```
enum
{
   FRONT,
   BACK
}
.
.
.
   if (frontOrBack == FRONT)
   {
      // Stuff
   }
   else if (frontOrBack == BACK)
   {
      // Some other stuff
   }
```